# How to pass component with content to GridItem in Vue-grid-layout?

Tags: vue.js, grid-layout, vuejs2, vue-component

Please help to understand how to pass a content to GridItems from Layout []'s  hash value.

I think that GridItem.i is a key value for GridItem. But how to link "content" component for a cell accordingly ?

This way is non-working:

html:

```
<grid-item v-for="item in layout"
               :x="item.x"
               :y="item.y"
               :w="item.w"
               :h="item.h"
               :i="item.i">
             {{item.c}}
</grid-item>
```

js:

```
let a = `<item>There I want div from component</item>`;

Vue.component('item', {
    props: [],
    template: `<div>Primer</div>
    `
});

var testLayout = [
   {"x":0,"y":0,"w":2,"h":2,"i":"1","c":"content1"},
   {"x":2,"y":0,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"2","c":"<item>There I want div from component</item>"},    
   {"x":4,"y":0,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"3","c":a},
];

var GridLayout = VueGridLayout.GridLayout;
var GridItem = VueGridLayout.GridItem;

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        GridLayout,
        GridItem,
    },
    data: {
        layout: testLayout,
    },
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2oh62tp/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the vue-grid-layout author.

The grid item uses a slot to add content, so I don't think v-html works properly when used on grid-item. Just do it like this:

```
<grid-item v-for="item in layout"
               :x="item.x"
               :y="item.y"
               :w="item.w"
               :h="item.h"
               :i="item.i">
             <div v-html="item.c"></div>
</grid-item>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/jw2mmmpq/1/

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have to use something like this:

```
<grid-item v-for="item in layout" v-html="item.c"></grid-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying hard to figure out this, I made a little progress. But this is not a complete answer.
Issue I'm facing here is the inner children of `item` component are being parsed as string not as html.

If anyone helps would be useful.

Here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/srinivasdamam/ev88z5qs/

Comment: Instead of `<component :is="item.k">{{ item.c })</component>`, 
use `v-html` argument: `<component :is="item.k" v-html="item.c"/>`

Comment: BUt it overrides the template. @yev